# Two Way AES Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm using a class that I found here for AES encryption/decryption. It does work correctly for me, but when I encrypt a string using the EncryptToString method, the encryption contains only numbers. I was expecting it to contain numbers, letters, and symbols. Do you know why it would only contain numbers? Thanks

This is the code I'm referring to:

```
 public class AESEncryption
{
    // These can be anything I desire but must be less than or equal to 255
    private byte[] Key = { 222, 237, 16, 14, 28, 26, 85, 45, 114, 184, 27, 192, 37, 112, 222, 209, 241, 24, 175, 144, 173, 53, 105, 29, 24, 26, 17, 218, 131, 236, 53, 209 };
    private byte[] Vector = { 146, 64, 101, 111, 23, 32, 113, 119, 231, 121, 211, 11, 99, 32, 104, 156 };


    private ICryptoTransform EncryptorTransform, DecryptorTransform;
    private System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTFEncoder;

    public AESEncryption()
    {
        //This is our encryption method 
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();

        //Create an encryptor and a decryptor using our encryption method, key, and vector. 
        EncryptorTransform = rm.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);
        DecryptorTransform = rm.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);

        //Used to translate bytes to text and vice versa 
        UTFEncoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    }

    /// -------------- Two Utility Methods (not used but may be useful) ----------- 
    /// Generates an encryption key. 
    static public byte[] GenerateEncryptionKey()
    {
        //Generate a Key. 
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        rm.GenerateKey();
        return rm.Key;
    }

    /// Generates a unique encryption vector 
    static public byte[] GenerateEncryptionVector()
    {
        //Generate a Vector 
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        rm.GenerateIV();
        return rm.IV;
    }


    /// ----------- The commonly used methods ------------------------------     
    /// Encrypt some text and return a string suitable for passing in a URL. 
    public string EncryptToString(string TextValue)
    {
        return ByteArrToString(Encrypt(TextValue));
    }

    /// Encrypt some text and return an encrypted byte array. 
    public byte[] Encrypt(string TextValue)
    {
        //Translates our text value into a byte array. 
        Byte[] bytes = UTFEncoder.GetBytes(TextValue);

        //Used to stream the data in and out of the CryptoStream. 
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        /* 
         * We will have to write the unencrypted bytes to the stream, 
         * then read the encrypted result back from the stream. 
         */
        #region Write the decrypted value to the encryption stream
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, EncryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        #endregion

        #region Read encrypted value back out of the stream
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] encrypted = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
        #endregion

        //Clean up. 
        cs.Close();
        memoryStream.Close();

        return encrypted;
    }

    /// The other side: Decryption methods 
    public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
    {
        return Decrypt(StrToByteArray(EncryptedString));
    }

    /// Decryption when working with byte arrays.     
    public string Decrypt(byte[] EncryptedValue)
    {
        #region Write the encrypted value to the decryption stream
        MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        decryptStream.Write(EncryptedValue, 0, EncryptedValue.Length);
        decryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        #endregion

        #region Read the decrypted value from the stream.
        encryptedStream.Position = 0;
        Byte[] decryptedBytes = new Byte[encryptedStream.Length];
        encryptedStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        encryptedStream.Close();
        #endregion
        return UTFEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }

    /// Convert a string to a byte array.  NOTE: Normally we'd create a Byte Array from a string using an ASCII encoding (like so). 
    //      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
    //      return encoding.GetBytes(str); 
    // However, this results in character values that cannot be passed in a URL.  So, instead, I just 
    // lay out all of the byte values in a long string of numbers (three per - must pad numbers less than 100). 
    public byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid string value in StrToByteArray");

        byte val;
        byte[] byteArr = new byte[str.Length / 3];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        do
        {
            val = byte.Parse(str.Substring(i, 3));
            byteArr[j++] = val;
            i += 3;
        }
        while (i < str.Length);
        return byteArr;
    }

    // Same comment as above.  Normally the conversion would use an ASCII encoding in the other direction: 
    //      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
    //      return enc.GetString(byteArr);     
    public string ByteArrToString(byte[] byteArr)
    {
        byte val;
        string tempStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= byteArr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            val = byteArr[i];
            if (val < (byte)10)
                tempStr += "00" + val.ToString();
            else if (val < (byte)100)
                tempStr += "0" + val.ToString();
            else
                tempStr += val.ToString();
        }
        return tempStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: by 'only numbers', do you mean a byte array?

Comment: it encodes bytes as integer values (3 digits) and concatenates thoes as a string and vice versa...

Comment: Did you look at the `ByteArrToString` method for even _one_ second? Your answer is in there (and in the comment for the `StrToByteArray` method).

Comment: I laughed after seeing that GenerateEncryptionKey and GenerateEncryptionVector methods

Comment: @ordag this must be the lo-salt version.

Comment: @Jodrell this is the lets leak the key version.

Comment: @ordag i laughed after seeing ByteArrToString method. it can be done 10 time faster with a stringbuilder:             var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i <= byteArr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                sb.Append(byteArr[i].ToString("000"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();

Answer (score 2):

it encodes bytes as integer values (3 digits) and concatenates thoes as a string and vice versa...

From the code and comments you posted:

```
/// Convert a string to a byte array.  NOTE: Normally we'd create a Byte Array from a string using an ASCII encoding (like so). 
//      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
//      return encoding.GetBytes(str); 
// However, this results in character values that cannot be passed in a URL.  So, instead, I just 
// lay out all of the byte values in a long string of numbers (three per - must pad numbers less than 100). 
public byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
```

AND the inverse method

```
// Same comment as above.  Normally the conversion would use an ASCII encoding in the other direction: 
//      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding(); 
//      return enc.GetString(byteArr);     
public string ByteArrToString(byte[] byteArr)
```

Comment: 3 digits or more acurately less than 256

Answer (score 0):

The AES algorithm takes and returns a byte array (`byte[]`) i.e. a set of 8bit numbers.

This is what all data inside your computer is stored as, whatever the data type, `string`, `Image`, `int` or any other. As you see, this line

```
//Translates our text value into a byte array.
Byte[] bytes = UTFEncoder.GetBytes(TextValue);
```

converts your 'clear' string into a 'clear' byte array, then runs it through the encryption algoritm. After encryption the byte array can no longer be decoded into a string (which is the point of encryption).

If you wanted to to store it as a string you could base64 encode so it was parser friendly but it will be unreadable garbage for a human either way.

If you use the `File.WriteAllBytes` function with the output from `Encrypt` like this

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\MyTestFile.txt", Encrypt("My Clear Text"));
```

It will store the bytes into a text file. If you then open "C:\MyTestFile.txt" with a text editor of your choice, you will see that the file does in fact contain all manner of charachters, both printing and non printing.

Assuming you use the right `key` and `vector`, the decryption code will turn the encrypted bytes back into 'clear' bytes and , as you can see

```
return UTFEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
```

return those bytes back as your original string.

If none of this makes any sense, then sorry, I've tried to keep it simple, perhaps take a step back and consider what a `byte` is, then how types work.

Comment: One more question. If you were going to encrypt something and store it in a database, could you encrypted it as a byte array and write the bytes out or would that not work since it would contain printing and non-printing characters?

Comment: @RichardKeslar
It would work if you stored it in a BLOB of sufficient size - but if you stored it previously as a text string, you would have to either create a new (temporary) column or store it as base 64 in the text field I guess.